# how to merge array with same key, value pair

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting, array-merge

how can I merge 2 array with same key, value pair in PHP below is the returned data.

```
array:8
  0 => array:3
    "group" => array:2
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "data 1"
    ]
    "brief" => array:5
    "tasks" => array:1
  ]
  1 => array:3
    "group" => array:2
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "data 1"
    ]
    "brief" => array:5
    "tasks" => array:1
  ]
  2 => array:3
  3 => array:3
  4 => array:3
  5 => array:3
    "group" => array:2
      "id" => 6
      "name" => "data 5"
    ]
    "brief" => array:5
    "tasks" => array:1
  ]
  6 => array:3
    "group" => array:2
      "id" => 6
      "name" => "data 5"
    ]
    "brief" => array:5
    "tasks" => array:1
  ]
  "totalHours" => "31"
]
```

I need to merge array[0] and array[1] same with array[5] and array[6] since they have both the same group key and value. Im using Laravel btw.

Comment: so do you really just mean removing duplicates?

Comment: if you call `array_unique($yourArray, SORT_REGULAR)` you will be returned a new array with no duplicate entries.

Since you mentioned you were using Laravel, it might be worth it to see if you can prevent duplicates being created in the first place when this array is created.

Comment: kinda removing duplicates, but in my case I need to merge it because I need to retain its brief and tasks. so in array[0] there should be 1group 2 brief and 2 tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following.  Detect which items in your array have the same group ids.  Then merge those items or the keys that you want merged.

Here I'm using array_merge_recursive, but it merges the id and name fields into an array, hence replacing the group key.  But do be careful here, you might wish to be more explicit in what you wish to merge.  Perhaps just the tasks and brief in your case.

```
<?php
$items = [
    [
        'group' => [
            'id' => '23',
            'name' => 'peach'
            ],
        'tasks' => ['foo', 'bar']
    ],
    ['big', 'fat', 'mamma'],
    [
        'group' => [
            'id' => '23',
            'name' => 'peach'
            ],
        'tasks' => ['baz', 'bat']
    ],
];

$groupIds = [];
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    if(isset($item['group'])) {
        $groupIds[$item['group']['id']][] = $key;
    }
}

foreach($groupIds as $group_id => $item_keys) {
    $merged_item = array();
    foreach($item_keys as $key) {
        $merged_item = array_merge_recursive($merged_item, $items[$key]);
        $merged_item['group'] = $items[$key]['group'];
        unset($items[$key]);
    }
    array_push($items, $merged_item);
}

var_export($items);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'big',
    1 => 'fat',
    2 => 'mamma',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'group' => 
    array (
      'id' => '23',
      'name' => 'peach',
    ),
    'tasks' => 
    array (
      0 => 'foo',
      1 => 'bar',
      2 => 'baz',
      3 => 'bat',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Laravel Collection [unique method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-unique).

This allows you to set a key by which to define what is unique.

You can select a nested property to merge on with the dot syntax. i.e. `group.id`.

```
$merged = collect($original)->unique('group.id');
```